# matplotlib figure size aspect ratio

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib, if I see the aspect ratio of the image using

```
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

is there a way I can get the actual figure to also match that?  Currently, I just get a lot of grey space.

Comment: what about `plt.figure(figsize=(x,x))`

Comment: but is there an automatic way to do it, without manually setting the size, based on what i've actually plotted?

Comment: are you really concerned about the gui plot, or would it be enough to just get a pdf / png without the large margins? If so use `plt.savefig('somefile.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')`.